# How to downgrade version of docker used by docker-machine and boot2docker?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine on OS:X. I would like to install Docker 1.11.2 into my boot2docker machine, however it looks like the combination of docker-machine and boot2docker are *always* pulling the latest release of [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/).

I have tried replacing `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso` with a manually downloaded iso matching 1.11.2, however this doesn't seem to actually change the version of docker.

I do not see [anything listed in docker-machine documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/) which suggests it to be possible to specify which iso or version of docker to use when creating the virtualmachine. I am using VirtualBox as driver.

How can I either downgrade the version of docker installed in my virtual machine or create a new one with a specific version installed?

Comment: Not sure, but they are probably going to get rid of it when the new one comes out of Beta. you might be better off using Vagrant (or similar) if you want more control.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new machine it is possible to specify where to get the boot2docker ISO from using the `--virtualbox-boot2docker-url` option. When doing that it will refrain from upgrading the machine to the latest version.

Example:

```
docker-machine create \
  --driver virtualbox \
  --virtualbox-memory 6144 \
  --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.10.10.1/24" \
  --virtualbox-cpu-count "2" \
  --virtualbox-disk-size "20000" \
  --virtualbox-boot2docker-url https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.12.2/boot2docker.iso \
  default
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two steps that need to happen to fully downgrade docker-machine.

First, download and replacing the `boot2docker.iso` file located at `~/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso`. When you create a new docker-machine, it defaults to using the cached iso. Manually replacing it with [whatever version iso you want](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases) is required.

This will then cause docker-machine to create the VM with the appropriate version of docker.

However, you also need to download a new version of [docker toolbox](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/download/v1.11.2/DockerToolbox-1.11.2.pkg) in order to have the previous version for the client, as well. I am not sure how to navigate to older versions than the linked (1.11.2) but you can change the download url to whatever version you want and it seems some of them are still hosted.

Comment: It doesn't default to using the cached version.

Comment: @ramblingpolak you have to do docker-machine create, not docker-machine upgrade.

Comment: docker-machine create will still upgrade.

```
cp ~/Downloads/boot2docker.iso ~/.docker/machine/cache/
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Default Boot2Docker ISO is out-of-date, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.12.1
(default) Downloading /Users/user/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.12.1/boot2docker.iso...
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following following steps:

1. Check your docker version:

   `$ docker -v
   Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24`
2. Download your docker version's of `boot2docker` (18.03.0-ce) from [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases?after=v18.04.0-ce-rc1) into your local:

   `wget https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.03.0-ce/boot2docker.iso -P ~/.docker/machine/cache/test/boot2docker-v18-03-0-ce.iso`
3. Create the `new_virtual_box_name` using the downloaded version of `boot2docker`:

   `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url ~/.docker/machine/cache/test/boot2docker-v18-03-0-ce.iso new_virtual_box_name`